# Facing issue with nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I want to do proxy_pass for 
`https://atmvpn.appdomain.cloud/sft-ui/sft/api/orgs/v1/org` in such a way that should be 
`https://dev.apnat.net/sft/api/orgs/v1/org`so while proxy_pass we need to remove `sft-ui` so I add below location in nginx.conf file

```
`location /sft-ui/sft/api {
      access_log off;
      rewrite ^/sft-ui/(.*)  /$1 break;
      proxy_pass <%= ENV["AMS_DOMAIN"] %>;
    }`
```

I have set **AMS_DOMAIN** as environment variable. But when I hit `https://atmvpn.appdomain.cloud/sft-ui/sft/api/orgs/v1/org` in browser I get error "502 Bad Gateway".

in Logs of openshift pod I can see:

`2020/06/05 07:06:46 [error] 11#11: *1 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.30.96.141, server: , request: "GET /sft-ui/sft/api/orgs/v1/org HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://104.18.12.180:443/sft/api/orgs/v1/org", host: "atmvpn.appdomain.cloud"`

`2020/06/05 07:06:46 [warn] 11#11: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.30.96.141, server: , request: "GET /sft-ui/sft/api/orgs/v1/org HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://104.18.12.180:443/sft/api/orgs/v1/org", host: "atmvpn.appdomain.cloud"`

Answer (score -1):

Just adding proxy_ssl_server_name on; its resolved

```
 location /sft-ui/sft/api {
          access_log off;
          rewrite ^/sft-ui/(.*)  /$1 break;
          proxy_pass <%= ENV["AMS_DOMAIN"] %>;
          #By setting to "on" can proxy to upstream hosts using SNI
          proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
```